# Foreign key as Primary key

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key, sqlyog

I designed tables like this:

```
table1: students
---------------------
PK id
name
number
...
---------------------

table2: students_score
---------------------
PK FK student_id
math_score
english_score
...
---------------------
```

**Question 1**

If some students doesn't have scores at all, is it good table design?

**Question 2**

If it's good design, then how can I make FK as PK in MySQL? I can't find out how. Everytime I try to make a relation like above SQLYog says this error: `Can't create table 'students.#sql-a31_2c8e' (errno: 150)`

Thanks

**Update**

I found an answer of the *question 2* [from here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,19755,259716#msg-259716). This was just a problem of type(int, signed int).

Comment: arugh. database-design.  I think the latest tread is to denormalize data.  Academics would, of course, ask for 5th normal form here.

Comment: It's all just speed vs flexibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest something more along these lines:

```
table1: students
---------------------
PK id
name
number
...
---------------------

table3: classes
---------------------
pk id
name

table2: students_score
---------------------
fk student_id
fk class_id
score
PK(student_id, class_id)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `UNIQUE` and `FOREIGN KEY` instead. It will allow you to use the `FOREIGN KEY` with your `students_score` table, and maintain the `student_id` column as unique.

Answer (score 1):

If some students doesn't have scores at all, is it good table design?

No, if some students doesn't have scores, there won't be (or shouldn't be) records on the students_score table. It is not a good design though, and that's why you get errors.

Your design should be something similar to:

```
students
---------------------
PK id
name
number

students_score
---------------------
FK student_id
math_score
english_score
...
```

Consider creating an `UNIQUE` index for your student_id on the `students_score` table, but that will limit your number of records per student to one, which maybe is not what you want.